# Is there a hot key for switching between 3D Object and Sculpt modes?

Tags: shortcut, object-mode, sculpt

In the past, I've found the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key useful for switching between edit and object modes.  But now that I'm getting into sculpting, I'm finding that I need to frequently switch between sculpt and object modes and the tab key simply toggles the current mode with edit mode.  The best hotkey combination I've found so far is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> which is kind of cumbersome since it involves an awkward <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in the left hand followed by a separate keystroke.

Is there an easier way to do this? I'd like to be able to do something simple like just press <kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>4</kbd> to switch modes.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the mouse in the direction of the option of the pie menu while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and once you release it with the mouse moved in the direction of the option you want it will get chosen. That might be more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The number buttons on the top of the keyboard are used to toggle  collections on and off, this can be a pain, and is throwback to Blenders old layer system. I have reassigned these to select the different modes.

If you go into preferences, select 'keymap' and search for collection, you will find the visibility settings for the first 10 collections. Disable all these associations by clicking on the cross next to the entry, be careful,  however, you can undo these changes by clicking the restore button at any time. Now you have freed up the row of number buttons ,so you can now set whatever you want to them. Click on 'Object Mode'(if that is the mode you are currently in), hover over the mode you want, Rt click and press the key you want to associate with that mode. Do this for all modes. Now you can quickly enter the mode you want with a single button push. Just remember in edit mode buttons 1,2 & 3 are used for different selection types, so from edit you will have the return to object mode using TAB. But the rest work fine and it is a lot easier than searching around the pie menu. If you are happy with the settings, you can save them in preferences, by clicking 'Save Preferences *'. The star symbol means that changes have not been saved. If you do not save the changes you made the old settings will be restored when you restart Blender.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a drawing tablet you can assign key stroke modifiers to express keys, allowing you to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, 2 or 4 a simple button press. Pretty sure you can do this with a gaming mouse with an assortment of buttons too.